# Why is the result always /254?

Tags: c

I am making one small `C` project to realize the encrypting. Most of them, I think, have been done. It can be successfully run also. But the result is always the same. I thought it may because I place `n=i%4` incorrectly, but it seems the same that I adjust it. no matter what I type, the answer is always `/254`.

What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int getText( char a[])
{
    char array[80];
    int i=0;
    printf("type your sentence\n");
    while( (array[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' ){}
    return i;
}

void EncryptArray(char a[], int length)
{   int i, n = 0;
    n = i%4;
    char row1[100], row2[100],row3[100];
    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (n==0) {
            row1[i]= a[i];
        }
        if (n==1 || n==3) {
            row2[i]=a[i];
        }
        if (n==2) {
            row3[i]=a[i];
        }
    }

    i=0;
    do {
        a[i]=row1[i];
        i++;
    } while (n=0);
    i=0;
    do {
        a[i]=row2[i];
        i++;
    } while (n==1 || n==3);
    i=0;
    do {
        a[i]=row3[i];
        i++;
    } while (n==2);
}

void PrintEncryptedArray(char a[], int length)
{
    printf("%s",a);
}

int main()
{   char a[80];
    int y;
    y=getText(a);
    EncryptArray(a, y);
    PrintEncryptedArray(a, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this line: 'void PrintEncryptedArray(char a[], int length)' will raise a compiler warning because the passed parameter 'length' is not used.

Comment: in the function:  EncryptArray(), 'n' is initialized to 0.  Nothing in the function changes 'n'.  So most of the code in that function will never be executed.

Comment: @user3629249: No, `n` is initialized to `0` and then assigned the value `i%4`. But `i` is uninitialized at that point, so `n` is garbage. (It might happen to be `0`.) Remember, `int i, n = 0;` is equivalent to `int i; int n = 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getText` function reads into the local variable `array` and you never do anything with that array afterwards, so the input is lost.

Probably you intended for it to read into the parameter `a`.

Comment: Of course, your code should be updated to protect against buffer overflows.

Comment: so you mean i need to change the input function?

Comment: Yes, take out `array` and write into `a` isntead

Comment: pass a second parameter that indicates the max length of a[] so that can be checked against 'i' to avoid a buffer overflow

Comment: then there is nothing coming out, means i still have other problems?

Comment: @johnwayyang `printf("%s",a);`, `n = i%4;`,`} while (n=0);`, also `n==0` has probrem

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, what are the problems?

Comment: @johnwayyang `"%s"` : string need NUL terminate. `i` uninitialize, `n=0` assign, not compare, `}while(n==?)` : `n` not change ... non stop loop.